# Why does Asia/Dubai timezone abbreviation differ between timezonedb and tzdata?

Tags: php, timezone, timezonedb

I'm using php timezonedb 2017.2.

How come it returns +04 instead of GST for Asia/Dubai timezone?
While default built in php tzdata returns GST.

```
$dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimezone('Asia/Dubai'));
$dt->format('T'); // returns either GST or +04
```

php -v = PHP 5.5.38 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2016 18:30:32)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, because time zone data changes over time. It sounds like `timezonedb` is up-to-date, but `tzdata`isn't.

This change was made in the 2017a release of the [IANA time zone data](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

From the announcement email - emphasis mine:

> Changes to past and future time zone abbreviations
>
> **Switch to numeric time zone abbreviations** for South America, as
>       part of the ongoing project of removing invented abbreviations.
>       This avoids the need to invent an abbreviation for the new Chilean
>       new zone.  Similarly, switch from invented to numeric time zone
>       abbreviations for Afghanistan, American Samoa, the Azores,
>       Bangladesh, Bhutan, the British Indian Ocean Territory, Brunei,
>       Cape Verde, Chatham Is, Christmas I, Cocos (Keeling) Is, Cook Is,
>       **Dubai**, East Timor, Eucla, Fiji, French Polynesia, Greenland,
>       Indochina, Iran, Iraq, Kiribati, Lord Howe, Macquarie, Malaysia,
>       the Maldives, Marshall Is, Mauritius, Micronesia, Mongolia,
>       Myanmar, Nauru, Nepal, New Caledonia, Niue, Norfolk I, Palau,
>       Papua New Guinea, the Philippines, Pitcairn, Qatar, Réunion, St
>       Pierre & Miquelon, Samoa, Saudi Arabia, Seychelles, Singapore,
>       Solomon Is, Tokelau, Tuvalu, Wake, Vanuatu, Wallis & Futuna, and
>       Xinjiang; for 20-minute daylight saving time in Ghana before 1943;
>       for half-hour daylight saving time in Belize before 1944 and in
>       the Dominican Republic before 1975; and for Canary Islands before
>       1946, for Guinea-Bissau before 1975, for Iceland before 1969, for
>       Indian Summer Time before 1942, for Indonesia before around 1964,
>       for Kenya before 1960, for Liberia before 1973, for Madeira before
>       1967, for Namibia before 1943, for the Netherlands in 1937-9, for
>       Pakistan before 1971, for Western Sahara before 1977, and for
>       Zaporozhye in 1880-1924.

Comment: So the updated one is correct! The reason I was confused is because switching from `GST` to `+04` seemed backwards. Thank you, I was missing the IANA link (this stuff is going to be super useful), but where exactly did you find that announcement email quote? Or more importantly, how did you know where to click to see that quote?

Comment: @TimoHuovinen: It's from the announcements mailing list. The archive is here: http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/ and you can subscribe/unsubscribe here: https://mm.icann.org/mailman/listinfo/tz-announce

Comment: In case it wasn't clear - the built-in tzdata in PHP is indeed timezonedb already.  PHP takes the most current timezonedb release at the time a PHP release is made.  You can simply call [`timezone_version_get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-version-get.php) to figure out which [version of timezonedb](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb) is embedded in the PHP distribution you have.  The timezonedb version scheme aligns loosly with the IANA version scheme, so 2017.2 is 2017b, etc.